# How do I make JavaScript functions change CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a lot of projects I have been making, I always had a problem that I wanted to make JavaScript change CSS styles. I tried reading other questions but it did not solve my answer. If a variable is above a certain number's value, like for example:

```
var points = 0;

if (points >= 50) {

  (make an image appear or show)

}
```

how would I then make an image appear? I figured out it might work if the image display is set to none in CSS, but how would I change that?

```js
var points = 0;

function add() {
  points += 1;
  score.innerHTML = points;

  if (points == 10) {
    score.innerHTML = "10";
    LV.innerHTML = 2;
  }
  if (points >= 30) {
    LV.innerHTML = 3;
  };

};

function reset() {

  points -= 1;
  score.innerHTML = points;

  if (points <= 0) {
    points = 0;
    score.innerHTML = points;
  };
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Determination Sans";
  src: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2552046/fonts/DeterminationSansWeb.woff") format('woff');
}

p {
  line-height: 1px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 5;
  font-family: determination sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#bootain {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: butt 3s infinite;
}

p {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  animation: textPulse 5s infinite;
}

.click {
  width: 70px;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
  box-shadow: red 5px 5px;
}

.score {
  color: white;
  animation: enchant 5s infinite;
}

.reset {
  animation: deactivatepulse 7s infinite;
  transform: scale(1);
}

button {
  color: white;
  animation: deactivatepulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes enchant {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  20% {
    color: #c4abff;
  }
  40% {
    color: #d9d6ff;
  }
  60% {
    color: #fae8ff;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: translatey(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}

@keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.50);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.55);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.50);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes butt {
  0% {
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 2 4 white;
  }
  20% {
    color: #4d4d4d;
  }
  40% {
    color: black;
  }
  60% {
    color: #687d7b;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes deactivatepulse {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: #a10000;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ff4d00;
  }
  56% {
    color: black;
  }
  70% {
    color: #ff4d00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bfac3b;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes buttonhover1 {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: #82fffd;
  }
  50%
}
```

```html
<h8 class="soulintro">THIS IS YOUR SOUL.</h8>
<br>



<img src="https://i.ibb.co/QmRsxNK/Sowl.png" class="click" style="width: 100px"></img>
<br>

<p id="LV">LV: 1</p>

<p id="score">SOUL power (XP): 0</p>
<button id="bootain" onclick="add();" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; font-family: determination sans; font-size: 11px;">Increase power level</button>

<button id="reset" onclick="reset();" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; font-family: determination sans; font-size: 11px;">Decrease power level</button>
<h7 class="characters"></h7>
```

Comment: JS cant change CSS. JS applies style by adding it as `inline-style`. You either overwrite the CSS with the highe specificty weight of the inline style or you use JS to add/remove classes with CSS changes.

Comment: [MDN Notes on Stylesheet api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) - the [CSSStyleSheet api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule), [cssRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules) - from that you should see how one might add/edit css rules on the fly

Comment: Which image do you want to show/hide

Comment: Thank you so much @decpk for editing the format! (I didn't know how it worked, I'm new)

Comment: this image, if the points reach 40, It could show up

Comment: <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NN5nVtv/spr-asriel-afterimager-full.png"></img>

Comment: @Skysurfer_kon added code

Comment: `<img>` is an empty tag. It does not have a closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it now!
The simplest way is by changing CSS, which can be done through:

document.getElementById("img").style.display="inline-block";

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var points = 0;

const img = document.getElementById("image")

if (points >= 50) {

  img.style.display = "block"

} else {
  img.style.display = "none";
}
```

JavaScript changes the inline styles of HTML elements, by adding the `style` attribute to the element. But if you don't want to use inline styles, then you could write to the `<style>` tag.
First, create a `style` tag in the `head` tag and then write

```
var styleEl = document.querySelector("style");
var points = 0;
styleEl.innerHTML = `img { display: ${points >= 50 ? 'block' : 'none' };}`
```

Also see: [W3Schools's tutorial for JavaScript DOM CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20DOM%20allows%20JavaScript%20to%20change%20the,you%20to%20execute%20code%20when%20an%20event%20occurs.)

Comment: the image has no id but a class. As such you cant use `getElementById`. You should use `querySelector(".click")` instead.

Comment: Yep. This was just an example though.

Answer (score 0):

Call function when `add` and `reset` function call.

```
function showHideImage() {
      if(points >= 50 ){
        image.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        image.style.display = "none";
      }
}
```

```js
var points = 0;
const image = document.querySelector("img");

function showHideImage() {
  if(points >= 50 ){
    image.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    image.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function add() {
  points += 1;
  score.innerHTML = points;

  if (points == 10) {
    score.innerHTML = "10";
    LV.innerHTML = 2;
  }
  if (points >= 30) {
    LV.innerHTML = 3;
  };
  
  showHideImage();
  
};

function reset() {

  points -= 1;
  score.innerHTML = points;

  if (points <= 0) {
    points = 0;
    score.innerHTML = points;
  };
  showHideImage();
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Determination Sans";
  src: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2552046/fonts/DeterminationSansWeb.woff") format('woff');
}

.img-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img{
  display: none;
}

p {
  line-height: 1px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 5;
  font-family: determination sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#bootain {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: butt 3s infinite;
}

p {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  animation: textPulse 5s infinite;
}

.click {
  width: 70px;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
  box-shadow: red 5px 5px;
}

.score {
  color: white;
  animation: enchant 5s infinite;
}

.reset {
  animation: deactivatepulse 7s infinite;
  transform: scale(1);
}

button {
  color: white;
  animation: deactivatepulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes enchant {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  20% {
    color: #c4abff;
  }
  40% {
    color: #d9d6ff;
  }
  60% {
    color: #fae8ff;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: translatey(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}

@keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.50);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.55);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.50);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes butt {
  0% {
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 2 4 white;
  }
  20% {
    color: #4d4d4d;
  }
  40% {
    color: black;
  }
  60% {
    color: #687d7b;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes deactivatepulse {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: #a10000;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ff4d00;
  }
  56% {
    color: black;
  }
  70% {
    color: #ff4d00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bfac3b;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes buttonhover1 {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: #82fffd;
  }
  50%
}
```

```html
<h8 class="soulintro">THIS IS YOUR SOUL.</h8>
<br>


<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QmRsxNK/Sowl.png" class="click" style="width: 100px"></img>
</div>
<br>

<p id="LV">LV: 1</p>

<p id="score">SOUL power (XP): 0</p>
<button id="bootain" onclick="add();" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; font-family: determination sans; font-size: 11px;">Increase power level</button>

<button id="reset" onclick="reset();" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; font-family: determination sans; font-size: 11px;">Decrease power level</button>
<h7 class="characters"></h7>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using inline events and styles the markup should be kept as clean as possible by using both Javascript & CSS externally as much as possible. You can, ( easier with a minor tweak to the HTML ), use a single event listener to perform the increase/decrease of points necessary to display the image. The image will only display if the `src` attribute is present so by modifying that image to use a `dataset` attribute for the source, `data-src` you can programmatically toggle the `src` attribute quite easily. The code below uses `incrementer` variable to speed testing- presumably this will be `1` for final version but set here at `10`

```js
let points=0;
let incrementer=1;

const lv=document.getElementById('LV');
const sp=document.getElementById('score');
const img=document.querySelector('img.click[data-src]');

document.querySelectorAll('button[data-task]').forEach(btn=>{
  btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    switch( this.dataset.task ){
      case 'increase':
        points+=incrementer;
      break;
      case 'decrease':
        points-=incrementer;
      break;
    }
    let level=lv.textContent;

    if( points >= 50 ){
      if( !img.hasAttribute('src') )img.src=img.dataset.src;
    }else{
      if( img.hasAttribute('src') )img.removeAttribute('src');
    }

    if( points > 0 && points % 10==0 && points < 40 )level=points/10;

    sp.textContent=points;
    lv.textContent=level;
  });
})
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Determination Sans";
  src: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2552046/fonts/DeterminationSansWeb.woff") format('woff');
}

p {
  line-height: 1px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 5;
  font-family: determination sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#bootain {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: butt 3s infinite;
}

p {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  animation: textPulse 5s infinite;
}

.click {
  width: 70px;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
  box-shadow: red 5px 5px;
}

.score {
  color: white;
  animation: enchant 5s infinite;
}

.reset {
  animation: deactivatepulse 7s infinite;
  transform: scale(1);
}

button {
  color: white;
  animation: deactivatepulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes enchant {
  0% {
  color: white;
  }
  20% {
  color: #c4abff;
  }
  40% {
  color: #d9d6ff;
  }
  60% {
  color: #fae8ff;
  }
  100% {
  color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: translatey(20px);
  }
  100% {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatey(0);
  }
}

@keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
  transform: scale(0.50);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
  transform: scale(0.55);
  opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
  transform: scale(0.50);
  opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes butt {
  0% {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2 4 white;
  }
  20% {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  }
  40% {
  color: black;
  }
  60% {
  color: #687d7b;
  }
  100% {
  color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes deactivatepulse {
  0% {
  color: black;
  }
  20% {
  color: #a10000;
  }
  50% {
  color: #ff4d00;
  }
  56% {
  color: black;
  }
  70% {
  color: #ff4d00;
  }
  90% {
  color: #bfac3b;
  }
  100% {
  color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes buttonhover1 {
  0% {
  color: black;
  }
  20% {
  color: #82fffd;
  }
  50%
}


button{width: 80px; height: 30px; font-family: determination sans; font-size: 11px;cursor:pointer}  
[data-text]:before{content:attr(data-text)}
```

```html
<h8 class="soulintro">THIS IS YOUR SOUL.</h8>
<img data-src='https://i.ibb.co/QmRsxNK/Sowl.png' class="click" alt='Heart animation' />

<p id='LV' data-text='LV:'>1</p>
<p id="score" data-text='SOUL power (XP):'>0</p>

<button id="bootain" data-task='increase'>Increase power level</button>
<button id="reset" data-task='decrease'>Decrease power level</button>

<h7 class="characters"></h7>
```

Comment: Wow! That seems comlicated.. It has a part I need, but the click is supposed to increase 1 level of SOUL power. Thanks though!

Comment: I totally missed that - have made a correction now which I think fixes it

Comment: thank you so much! But... how do I answer other people's questions? (where do I find them)

Comment: `"how do I answer other people's questions? (where do I find them)"` ? I don't know what you mean ~ which questions? which users?

Comment: I found it now!

Comment: But the new snippet is functional! It shows exactly what I need! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -2):

Upload the picture in the image file and put the right path for it in  code

var points = 0;

if (points >= 50) {

var img = document.createElement("img");
 
img.src = "1.png";
var src = document.getElementById("x");
 
src.appendChild(img);
}

Comment: down-voted for following reason: Anwser is badly formatted. As such it is hard to read and understand. As such I already would rate it as "low-quality". Also I have trouble to see how you solution would work in this case. Even if it would work, it would be a bad approach, there more simple and less hacky solutions.